# How do i Get data to show on other pages?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> I made the changes to the Get & Post, but it gives nothing, i think its the form that is making this difficult, the form just below this section here, am i doing something wrong? i can't tell but know one thing for sure when i use the 'name' and not 'submit' & 'go' for the GET & the POST i get error saying undefined index:'name', whats up with that, i did what you said but nothing!

/////////////The Form/////////////////////

```
<form method="post" action="search_govern.php?go" id="searchform">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yell">
</form>
```

///////////End of Form/////////////////////

```
<?php   

//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//if(isset($_GET['go'])){
//if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
//$name=$_POST['name'];
////////////////////////////////////////
```

> The problem I think is here, but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong you can you please point out my errors or show me an example of this please!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
$raw_name = $_GET['name'] ;

if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $raw_name )){
$name=$raw_name;
////////////////////////////////////////

include "connect/connect.php";

//-query the database table
$sql="SELECT userId, Attribute, Name FROM government  WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%' OR   Attribute LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY userid ASC";

///////////////////////// PAGINATION CLASS////////////////////////////////////


class Pagination {

public $current_page;
public $per_page;
public $total_count;

public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0){
 $this->current_page = (int)$page;
 $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
 $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
}

   public function offset() {

   return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
}

  public function total_pages() {
   return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
}

  public function previous_page() {
  return $this->current_page - 1;
}

  public function next_page() {
  return $this->current_page + 1;
}

   public function has_previous_page() {
    return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
}

    public function has_next_page() {
        return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
    }
}

///////////////////////////END OF PAGINATION CLASS///////////////////////////////

$curent_page   = isset($_GET['page'])&&(int)$_GET['page'] !=0 ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1 ;
$per_page = 7 ;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM government ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$total = mysql_result($result , 0);

$pagination    = new Pagination($curent_page , $per_page , $total);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         //echo 'perpage      : '.$pagination->per_page.'<br />';
         //echo 'offset       : '.$pagination->offset().'<br />';

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$rows_to_show = "SELECT userId, Attribute, Name FROM government WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%' OR Attribute LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT {$pagination->per_page} OFFSET   {$pagination->offset()}";

if($pagination->total_pages() > 1 ){
         echo '<div id="pagination_div">';
          if($pagination->has_next_page()){

          echo '<span><a href="search_govern.php?page='.$pagination->next_page();
          echo '&name='.$name;
          echo'" >> </a></span>' ;

          }
          for($i=1 ; $i <= $pagination->total_pages() ; $i++ ){
             if($i == $pagination->current_page ){
             echo  '&nbsp;<strong>'.$i.'&nbsp;</strong>';
             }
             else   {                 
             echo '<span><a href="search_govern.php?page='.$i;
             echo '&name='.$name;
             echo'"> '.$i.' </a></span>';  
             }
          }
          if($pagination->has_previous_page()){

            echo'<span><a href="search_govern.php?page='.$pagination->previous_page();
            echo '&name='.$name;
            echo'" >  < </a></span>';
          } 

        echo ' </div> ';

         }


$dtotal = mysql_query($rows_to_show);

    echo "$dtotal";

if ( $dtotal === FALSE ){ //////////// check to see if the query fails
       die(mysql_error());
    }
    else{


//-create while loop and loop through result set
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dtotal)){
$userId=$row['userId'];
$Attribute=$row['Attribute'];
$Name=$row['Name'];


//-display the result of the array
echo "<p style=\"margin:2px 0px 5px 0px;\" >"; 
echo "<p>" ."<a href=\"search_govern.php?id=$userId\"> "  . $Name . "</a></p>";
echo "</p>";
}
}
}
else{
echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please enter a search query</p>";
}
}
}
```

?>

Comment: What happens when you echo $limit on $pn=2?

Comment: Put an "echo $limit" statement after you declare the $limit var.  Then see what that echoes when you go to the second page ($pn=2)

Comment: Ok, i did what you suggested but the problem is still there!, and i thought you should know, this is paginating a search result from my data base if that helps idk! my brain is melting right now!

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood, I'm trying to see what the value of your $limit variable is by echoing it.  That shouldn't solve any problems, but your $limit var could possibly be a source for errors.  If you echo $limit, you should be able to see it's value written somewhere on the page when you load it. Something like "LIMIT 7,7"

Comment: ok something happened just now, i did echoed the limit, and i did get limit 0,7 and then limit 7,7, but when i did the changes to the limit variable that you suggested it didn't work so i came back here to tell you and the page went wack on me

Comment: You suggested i used $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .($pn * $itemsPerPage);

$limit = 'LIMIT ' . $itemsPerPage .' OFFSET ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

Comment: ok everything looks good . but your query obviously fails . you have to check that before using mysql_fetch_array . i've edited my answer look at my last block of code right below EDIT . and post every edit that you do here

Answer (score 0):

i suggest a simpler and cleaner code

here is a simple pagination class:

```
class Pagination {

  public $current_page;
  public $per_page;
  public $total_count;

  public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0){
    $this->current_page = (int)$page;
    $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
    $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
  }

  public function offset() {

    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
  }

  public function total_pages() {
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
    }

  public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
  }

  public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
  }

    public function has_previous_page() {
        return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
    }

        public function has_next_page() {
            return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
        }
}
```

save it in a .php file and include it on your page
here is how you use it :

$pagination    = new Pagination($curent_page , $per_page , $total);

```
 $curent_page   // get it from url with GET method
e.g 
$curent_page   = isset($_GET['page'])&&(int)$_GET['page'] !=0 ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1 ;
```

-

```
$per_page // you have to define how many rows do you want to show in the page
e.g
 $per_page = 20 ;
```

-

```
 $total // you have to  count all of the rows in your table 

e.g
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$tbl` ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql , $db_connection);
    $total = mysql_result($result , 0);


now you can create a pagination obj
 $pagination    = new Pagination($curent_page , $per_page , $total);
```

-

```
     $pagination->offset() // use this as offset in your query in each
     page 

 $pagination->per_page // use this as LIMIT in your query

        e.g
        $rows_to_show = "SELECT * FROM `$tbl` LIMIT {$pagination->per_page} OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
```

and finally creating the html pagination at the bottom of page

```
 if($pagination->total_pages() > 1 ){
             echo '<div id="pagination_div">';
              if($pagination->has_next_page()){

              echo '<span><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->next_page();
              echo'" >> </a></span>' ;

              }
              for($i=1 ; $i <= $pagination->total_pages() ; $i++ ){
                 if($i == $pagination->current_page ){
                 echo  '&nbsp;<strong>'.$i.'&nbsp;</strong>';
                 }
                 else   {                 
                 echo '<span><a href="index.php?page='.$i;
                 echo'"> '.$i.' </a></span>';  
                 }
              }
              if($pagination->has_previous_page()){

                echo'<span><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->previous_page();
                echo'" >  < </a></span>';
              } 

            echo ' </div> ';

             }
```

/////////////////////////////////////////// EDIT 2 ////////////////////////////////////////

```
 /// $name may be sent to the page via post/form   OR via get/url so you have to be prepare for both , so this is how you get $name at the top of page 

 if(isset($_POST['name']))
 $raw_name = $_POST['name'] ;
 if(isset($_GET['name']))
 $raw_name = $_GET['name'] ;

if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $raw_name )){
$name=$raw_name;
///// do other stuff
```

//////// and as for pagination you have to send $name to each page

```
 if($pagination->total_pages() > 1 ){
             echo '<div id="pagination_div">';
              if($pagination->has_next_page()){

              echo '<span><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->next_page();
              echo '&name='.$name;
              echo'" >> </a></span>' ;

              }
              for($i=1 ; $i <= $pagination->total_pages() ; $i++ ){
                 if($i == $pagination->current_page ){
                 echo  '&nbsp;<strong>'.$i.'&nbsp;</strong>';
                 }
                 else   {                 
                 echo '<span><a href="index.php?page='.$i;
                 echo '&name='.$name;
                 echo'"> '.$i.' </a></span>';  
                 }
              }
              if($pagination->has_previous_page()){

                echo'<span><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->previous_page();
                echo '&name='.$name;
                echo'" >  < </a></span>';
              } 

            echo ' </div> ';

             }
```

Comment: ok i did the changes and one thin came to my attention do i put this code just as it is like so                                   $pagination->offset();
$pagination->$per_page;

Comment: yes . you can edit you code and post the new one this way i can say if you do anything wrong

Comment: Check out! change that i made on my page just below the code you suggested! Thank you for you help though i appreciate it very much!

Comment: the error i am getting is, Notice: Undefined property: Pagination::$7  and        Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string

Comment: i told you to edit and post the new code , what is the line and file of the error ? and do edit your code and post the new one

Comment: Ok max, i did the changes and i still get an error, it says Undefined property: Pagination::$7, Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string, what am i doing wrong? Look ant the last block of code above just under what you wrote!

Comment: i'm sorry maybe i'm not being clear enough . you have to edit your question , delete the old code and replace it with the new code which you have wrote using my class . i cant tell you what your doing wrong unless i see your code. anyway your putting the wrong thing! in front of one of these "$pagination->" .try to echo $pagination->offset() and $pagination->$per_page before you run the query and put a exit; after the echos so you don't get the query error

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i made the changes i changed it up above the first post, still no luck don't know what i'm doing wrong! Sorry for nagging you!

Comment: i made the changes check out what's going on up top, still no go!

Comment: so you got the first page working ? another thing is on the pagination you have to pass the $name variable via url on each page ! you send $name to the first page via post/form but when you click on the 2nd pages you should also send the $name in the url . take a look at EDIT 2

Comment: I made the changes to the Get & Post, but it gives nothing, i think its the form that is making this difficult, the form just below this section here, am i doing something wrong? i can't tell but know one thing for sure when i use the 'name' and not 'submit' & 'go' for the GET & the POST i get error saying undefined index:'name', whats up with that, i did what you said but nothing, I appreciate the help, thank you. sir, i think maybe i'm doing somthing wrong!

Comment: your doing it wrong it's not what i wrote , look again at my first block of code right below EDIT2 . the if statements should be separated not inside each other . i marked your code with stars

Comment: Can you show a clear example of that please i'm not understanding, and the code above is just not making much sence, in order for me to get the info from the database i have to $_POST['submit']; and $_GET['go']; so where does $_GET['name']; fit in there, its not bringing up any data when i use what you suggested! Some still may be wrong!

Comment: I figured it out, thanks alot for all the help, i just have to fix one thing the data is showing on the other pages thats great, now i have to find a way to not show the Next and Back when the search results are less than 5 and show them when the results are more than 5.